# Clicking on a div that contains span, doesn't trigger onclick event - React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a div, and inside I am rendering spans based on some conditions. If the component has some children, I'd like this div to expand. It works fine if I click on this div on an area outside of the inner span.

An example, is the following [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zjlY.png). When clicking on the row, it expands the area to show items like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ewpC.png). However, when I click on the header text, it's not working, the on click event doesn't fire.

Here's my code:

```
 <div className={headerStyles.header} onClick={(e) => this.selectHeader(e, this.props.items.length)}>
    {this.props.items.length > 0 && 
          <span className={headerStyles.expand} style={{ color: this.props.headerNameColor }}></span>
                    }
          <span style={{ color: this.props.headerNameColor }}  >{this.props.headerName}</span>
                    {this.props.headerUrl &&
                        <a
                            style={{ color: this.props.headerNameColor }}
                            href={this.props.headerUrl}
                            data-interception="off"
                            target="_blank"
                            title="Open link in a new tab">
                            <i className={['ms-Icon', 'ms-Icon--OpenInNewWindow', headerStyles.openNewTab].join(' ')}></i>
                        </a>
                    }
                </div>
```

Here's the function that gets called when clicking the header:

```
 selectHeader(e, numOfItems) {
        if (e.target.children.length > 0 && numOfItems > 0) {
            e.target.children[0].classList.toggle(headerStyles.expand)
            e.target.children[0].classList.toggle(headerStyles.collapse)
            e.target.parentElement.querySelector(`.${headerStyles.items}`).classList.toggle(headerStyles.hidden)
        }
        else if(this.props.headerUrl){

        }
    }
```

Any guidance is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What does the function `this.selectHeader` look like? The event target will be different depending on which inner element you are clicking on, and if you're passing that event to a different function, it needs to handle that carefully.

Comment: Hi @jered, please check my updated post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `pointerEvents: 'none'` style to the `span` tags so it won't get any mouse event. This will make the `event.target` to always be the `div`

Comment: That was amazing. Thanks. I couldn't upvote your response as I don't have enough rep.!

Comment: I'm sorry but I think this is terrible advice for this situation. It advocates for a complete workaround of how React is supposed to operate. Using `event.target` and `classList.toggle` to imperatively modify the DOM outside of React is a nasty habit to get into that will only cause problems later on. I considered this solution in my own answer and explicitly omitted it because of how problematic it is.

Answer (score 1):

As I suspected, you're trying to do something with the `event.target` value inside of `selectHeader`. That won't work very well because `event.target` will change depending on which element you clicked on inside of your div. It won't always be the outer "parent" element.

You're also trying to read data imperatively from the DOM, which is not a very "React" way of doing things. In fact, within your function you're doing a `classList.toggle(headerStyles.hidden)` which is in direct conflict with React managing the state and rendering of your app. All the data you need should live within the state of your React application - you shouldn't need to query the DOM at all.

Ditch `event.target` and `classList.toggle` and find a way to do it using React state. For example, when you click the div you could simply toggle the "expanded" state of your component, and use that state to determine which CSS class to render:

```
<div onClick={() => {this.setState({isExpanded: !this.state.isExpanded})}} >
  <span className={this.state.isExpanded ? headerStyles.expand : headerStyles.collapse} ></span>
</div>
```

Comment: It was a CSS issue after all. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Dan I considered the other answer and specifically omitted it because it runs directly contrary to how React is intended to be used and can cause lots of weird problems later on. Please reconsider.

Comment: Thanks @jered. I am binding the .click event on the parent div itself, not on any of the child elements. So the function selectedHeader will only fire when the div is clicked, and e is going to reference the div always. Correct?

Comment: I totally agree for the classList.toggle though, it's not a react way and I should change it.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using arrow functions inside the JSX here. `e` object is always passed since this is an event handler, and your `props` are accessible from your handler:

```
selectHeader = (e) => {
     const numOfItems = this.props.items.length;
     // rest of the code...

 }
```

inside render method:

`<div onClick={this.selectHeader}>`

Comment: it didn't make any difference, the expand/collapse still works, but not when clicking on the header.